# Reset link strength D3 force

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mvLf579a/284/

This fiddle allows you to lay out the force network using the D3 radial layout as well as reset the layout to the default force layout. However, the link strength doesn't seem to be working correctly when resetting.

Heres the radial function :

```
function radial() {
  simulation
    .force("charge", d3.forceCollide().radius(10))
    .force("r", d3.forceRadial(function(d) {
    return 100
        return d.id < 5 ? 100 : 200;
      }, width / 2, height / 2).strength(function(d) {
      return 1
        // set radial force to 0 if it has the id we're looking for
        if(d.id == 3) return 0
        // otherwise keep the strength at 1
        else return 1
      })
    )
    // turning off previously set forces
    //.force('link', null)
    .force('x', null)
    .force('y', null)

  simulation.alpha(1).restart()
    }
```

Here's the resetting function :

```
function reset(){
simulation
  .force("link", d3.forceLink()
    //.id(function(d) {return d.id;})
    .strength(1))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .force('r', null)

  simulation.alpha(1).restart()

}
```

I thought using the following line would reset the link and the links strength :

```
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().strength(1))
```

If you open the fiddle, drag the linked nodes, they will drag the other nodes with it. (Bear in mind, I have duplicated the data, so sometimes when you drag one node it will drag a different one).

Then press 'radial', this will lay them out in the radial layout.

Then press 'reset', this should go back to how it starts, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: you don't do anything about the position of the nodes so they start where they are when you press `reset`, so your objects differ from the `initial` run

Comment: @riov8 sorry perhaps I didn't explain. The force returns but when I drag there is no strength in the links, so it doesn't drag the connected nodes when dragging nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must not add a new link force but modify the existing link force

```
function reset() {
  simulation.force("link").strength(1);
  simulation
    // .force("link", d3.forceLink()
    //   //.id(function(d) {return d.id;})
    //   .strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
    .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
    .force('r', null)

  simulation.alpha(1).restart()
}
```